# Active Admin cancan ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::AdminUsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I have this in :
    ability.rb

```
  def initialize(user)    
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :manage, AdminUser, :id => user.id
      end
  end
```

and in application_controller.rb:

```
def access_denied(exception)
  redirect_to admin_dashboard_path , :alert =>  exception.message
end
```

Also I have added the adapter for active admin in intializer/active_admin.rb:

```
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
```

When I go this url which he is not authorized to (e.g: http://admin.localhost.com:3000/admin/admin_users/1). Its giving error as:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::AdminUsersController#show
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by upgrading active_admin gem to gem 'activeadmin','0.6.3'.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised when Active Record cannot find record by given id or set of ids. Please check whether you have an entry in the admin_users table with id 1. Refer to the image below for better understanding of the error.

[image]

Comment: Yes the id is present at my database user.id 1 is present but as the current user does not have authority to view the other user that's why its giving the error.

Comment: @dinshawraje ok, seems like the logic is somehow working. Can the user with correct credentials view the page ?